# Unable to save a PDF if opened in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, pdf

I wrote an ASP.NET (C#) application to create online a PDF and show it in a browser.

```
    string path = @pdf_path;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);      

    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response. AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }
```

If I use Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox I can save and print it. BUT if I open it with Chrome and I click the save button, the aspx page will be saved, not the PDF.

How is it possible to enable Chrome to show the PDF or show and advise the user to enable some functionality?

Comment: I guess you should install pdf add-on on chrome

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome PDF mode you just move your mouse pointer close to the lower right corner and you get a small toolbar with a save button.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to force the browser to download the file add this header

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Sample.pdf");
```

---

but your codes works in chrome if you enable its pdf viewer :

The recent releases of Google Chrome (6 and up) have PDF support built-in, but it's not enabled by default.

type **about:plugins** in chrome and search for **pdf viewer** and enable it

[How To Enable the Built-in PDF Viewer in Google Chrome](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-enable-built-pdf-viewer-google-chrome.htm)